# Failed Packaging Spring-Boot Application into Jar File

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jar, docker-container, mongo-java-driver

I'm trying to dockerize my spring boot app and then connect it to a mongodb docker container sitting at `172.17.0.2:27017`.

Sadly when the **`./mvnw clean package`** tries running the app, it fails while trying to connect to the container at **`new MongoClient("172.17.0.2", 27017)`** (since it cannot connect form localhost perhaps), and so the `JAR` file is never created.

I believe if I could somehow put my app in a docker container, it might connect to the mongodb container (since another mongo container instance can connect to the first one. [see docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)) .
So the question is that is it possible force spring boot to create the Jar without running the app itself?

Answer (score 1):

probably you have a test with @SpringBootTest annotation. 
To generate JAR file you can try to do  `./mvnw -DskipTests=true clean package`